# How to convert svg images to svg font?

Tags: linux, windows, fontforge

How can I convert multiple SVG images to single SVG font with a fontforge script or any other single windows or linux executable.

I don't have any Java, Perl, Ruby or whatever else on my server, so no script in them, please.

Comment: Can you use python? fontforge has a plugin to script with python on it, it also has the bash script alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't have python there. I just changed my program to not use SVG fonts.